# Why sendemail is not working in k8s container?

Tags: image, alpine

my smtp server is in another server, trying to send the mails from k8s container but it says

ERROR:
mailscript.sh: line 56: sendemail: command not found

while running the script from smtp, it will send the mails but not from k8s container

I can telnet from same cluster to smtp server. there is no issue between them

Same command working in smtp server but not from k8s container

command:
sendemail -f $sender_email -t $To -u $subject -s $server:$host_port -m "$HTML_CONTENT" -v -o message-charset=$CHARSET

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. You might consider spending some time looking at other posts, seeing what attracts good quality responses, upvotes, and what gets downvoted/closed. Generally people here are in favour of reading error messages and using them to guide further investigation; if the error says "command not found" then the fault is unlikely to be a network connectivity issue. When an error message indicates a specific line in a specific file, then it is considered appropriate to quote at least the line in question.

Comment: Assuming you copied and pasted the error message accurately, then it is likely that "sendemail" is not available in your container - the only "sendemail" I have come across is a null mailer often used as in place of sendmail.

Comment: So, If I installed the sendmail in container it will work rt? and I see on google there is no much about it.

Comment: CHECK THE ERROR AGAIN CAREFULLY - you said it was complaining about "sendemail" not "sendmail"

Comment: sorry Its typo 
it says
sendemail: command not found

Comment: yup and sendemail sounds like a auto correction issue. the command is `sendmail` not `sandemail`

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get a `command not found` is exactly that: you're calling on a command/programme that can't be found.

Either:

- the [`sendemail`](https://packages.debian.org/unstable/sendemail) dependancy  has not been installed.
- the `sendemail` dependancy  has been installed, but your $PATH doesn't contain the location where it is installed,
  you solve that by amending $PATH or by using the absolute path in your scripts, i.e. use something like `/path/to/bin/sendemail`
- you made a typo, because the canonical command is [`sendmail`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sendmail.sendmail) and `sendemail`.
  Note: [`sendmail`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sendmail.sendmail) doesn't support all the switches and commandline options that your script is expecting.